# Rails association query based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

```
class ConferenceSession < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :conference_sessions

end


class ConferenceSession < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :conference

  has_and_belongs_to_many  :users

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :conference_sessions

end
```

and a conference_sesssions_users table. Admin can allow specific people to attend a particular session. So I want to form a query that whenever a user logs in and selects a conference he should be allowed to see only those sessions where the admin has allowed him to.

I've done this to get the specific session by doing

```
scope :visibility,
    lambda { |user_id| joins('INNER JOIN conference_sessions_users 
                              ON conference_sessions_users.conference_session_id = conference_sessions.id').
                              where('conference_sessions_users.user_id = ?', user_id) }
```

but this only returns the specific people, what if the session is visible to all the users, what should the condition be for the same.

Answer (score 0):

you could change condition to `where(conference_sessions_users: { user_id: user_ids})` which would translate to something like this: `WHERE conference_sessions_users.user_id in (1st_id, 2nd_id)`. Of course you should pass array of ids in that case as `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

It is a good case to use merge

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge